# Handle state update and call a function simultaneously to send the updated data to my backend

Tags: reactjs

I have a Checkbox:

```
<Checkbox 
  value={data.completed}
  onChange={(val) => {
    dispatch({
      type: "SET_FIELD",
      field: "completed",
      value: val,
    });
    updateData();
  }}

// Initialize State
const initialState = {
  completed: false
}

// Reducer
 const [data, dispatch] = useReducer(
   reducer,
   initialState,
 );

// Send data to my backend
function updateData() {
  ...send data...
}
```

Right now, updateData() will send "incorrect" data to my backend after I have clicked on the Checkbox, because it gets called before the new state was set by my reducer function.

Chat-GPT was recommending using useEffect but it had some downsides and does not feel right to me.

How can I successfully send the correct data to my backend, after the new state was set in dispatch(..)?

Comment: `Chat-GPT was recommending using useEffect but it had some downsides and does not feel right to me.` Can you be more specific about the downsides? `useEffect` is indeed a tool that can be used for this kind of thing. Your other option is to pass a parameter to updateData telling it what you want to send.